# Django: perform action after related objects are saved

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two models:

```py
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    create_report = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

They are registered in admin like this:

```py
class BookInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = PurchaseOrderItem

@admin.register(PurchaseOrder)
class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (PurchaseOrderInline,)
```

I create an author and two books through Django admin. After I hit the 'Save' button, if `Author.create_report == True` I would like to see a report saying the following:

> Author Whoever-he-is has written the following books:
>
> - Title-of-the-first-book
> - Title-of-the-first-book

(Where the report should appear or how to render the template are not relevant questions here, let's skip them.)

My first idea was to overwrite `Author.save()` method:

```py
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.create_report:
        self.write_report(name=self.name, books=self.book_set.all())
```

The problem is that `Author.save()` method is executed before `Book` objects are saved and so `self.book_set.all()` is empty.

One workaround would be to use some other `ModelAdmin` function (for instance `log_addition()`), which fires after `Book` objects are saved, but as I wish to use the same functionality out of admin, too, it is not the best solution.

Can I somehow achieve the result without using the admin layer functions?

Comment: Shouldn't `author = models.ForeignKey(Seller, on_delete=models.PROTECT)` be `author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.PROTECT)`?

Comment: You're right. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

The `book_set.all()` will be `Null` initially, because there is no `Book` related to the `Author` at the time of author creation. So, what I'm suggesting is, **generate the report whenever a `Book` is created**.

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    create_report = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pk = self.pk  # pk will be None like objects if self is new instance
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        if not pk and self.author.create_report:
            write_report(name=self.author.name, books=self.author.book_set.all())
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I use this approach in some cases, but here it doesn't really meet the needs. Your solution would show two reports in the above case, but the problem is that I need to show the report only once if and only if all books are saved. Do you have any suggestions for that?

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar issue. I think this is exactly the reason why Django introduced signals. You can fire and catch a signal of the created Books/Authors and then fire an action from there that creates some sort of report.

But I get your point (since I am feeling the same pain) ... id would be great is this would work straight from the model.